# The center of a group and a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Say we have a homorphism $\phi : G \longrightarrow H$. I'm just trying to understand how will the elements of the center of $G$ behave under $\phi$ especially if $ \phi(G)=H$.

Comment: Elements of $Z(G)$ will map to elements of $Z(\phi(G))$ but not necessarily to elements of $Z(H)$.

Comment: Um, you mean that $\phi(G) = H$? And unless we have a specific question, all we can give you is that $\phi(Z(G)) \subseteq Z(\phi(G))$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $z $ be in the center of $G$. Then for any $g\in G$ we have the following:

$\phi(z)\phi(g) = \phi(zg) = \phi(gz) = \phi(g)\phi(z)$. So $\phi$ maps an element of the center of $G$ to an element that commutes with the image of $G$ under $\phi$. Thus if $\phi(G)= H$ then $\phi(Z(G)) \subseteq Z(H)$.

Comment: As Patrick Da Silva points out, this is about all we can give you.